# webview.evalJS(). not working when calling a js function by passing arguments in html file

Tags: javascript, webview, appcelerator-mobile

The function is not called when I pass arguments to a js function by means of the `webview.evalJS` method:

```
var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
    url:'changefont/index.html'
});
done.addEventListener('click',function(){                             
    webview.evalJS("changeFontProperty(selected_font,selected_fsize);");
});
```

and the function in the HTML file is:

```
function changeFontProperty(cssProperty,fontValue) {
    $('body').css(cssProperty, fontValue);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried some methods and I got it like this..

We have to call the method like this...

```
    webview.evalJS("changeFontProperty('" + selected_font + "','" + selected_fsize + "');");
```

So my problem is solved.

It may be helpful to others...